# node.js connent modul error information

Tags: node.js

I use the nodejs connent modul code for sample. app.js follow this:

```
var connect = require("connect");

connect(
  connect.static(__dirname + "/public"),
  // create a router to handle application paths
  connect.router(function(app) {
    app.get("/sayHello/:firstName/:lastName", function(req, res) {
      var userName = req.params.firstName + " " + req.params.lastName,
        html = "<!doctype html>" + "<html><head><title>Hello " + userName + "</title></head>" + "<body><h1>Hello, " + userName + "!</h1></body></html>";

      res.end(html); 
    });
  }) 
).listen(8000);
```

node app.js excute its, print error message on console of this:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object function createServer() {
  function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); }
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  utils.merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [].slice.apply(arguments);
  return app;
} has no method 'router'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yangzhaojie/tech/nodejs/devsample/app4.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

os: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

node: 0.6.11

connent: 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old tutorial or something. The router middleware was removed from Connect some time ago: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/262

You can either use another module like this one ([connect-router](https://github.com/crcn/connect-router)) or switch to Express.

Comment: Thx, It's case in connent version. Same question on the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571239/mac-os-x-nodejs-has-no-method-router-error