# How do I fix connect.router?

Tags: node.js, routes, express, connect

I'm working my way through [Node for Front End devs](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hfmZ2jex894C), and as people on SO have already [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571239/mac-os-x-nodejs-has-no-method-router-error), Connect no longer has a module for routing. Some people have advised using Express, but I'm unsure of the exact syntax.

The example I am working through is hosted here:
**github.com/garann/node-for-frontend-devs/blob/master/03-03.js**

I would in turn like to finish the tutorial on templating:
js: **github.com/garann/node-for-frontend-devs/blob/master/04-02.js**
html: **github.com/garann/node-for-frontend-devs/blob/master/public/parent.html**
and was wondering whether people think it might be better to ditch these Connect based tutes and just learn how to use Express? As routing will most likely require Express anyway..

Thanks to SO excellent spam protection, I've had to remove the https:// portion of the github links.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd ditch those tutorials and move on to Express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use this: https://github.com/baryshev/connect-route

**UPDATE**

In your project folder execute:

```
npm install connect-route
```

Updated code from your example:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var connectRoute = require("connect-route");

connect(
  connect.static(__dirname + "/public"),
  connectRoute(function(app) {
    app.get("/sayHello/:firstName/:lastName", function(req, res) {
      var userName = req.params.firstName + " " + req.params.lastName,
        html = "<!doctype html>" +
          "<html><head><title>Hello " + userName + "</title></head>" +
          "<body><h1>Hello, " + userName + "!</h1></body></html>";

      res.end(html);
    });
  })
).listen(8000);
```

Point your browser to:

http://[your_host_here]:8000/sayHello/nick/name

Comment: Ok, but how would I use it in this case exactly? Sorry, total noob!

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

**connect.router** was removed in version 2.x. I took the code from 1.x and I published it as `connect_router`.

### Install

```
npm install --save connect_router
```

### Usage

```
if (!connect.router) {
  connect.router = require('connect_router');
}

function route(rest) {
  rest.get('/api/hello', function (req, res) {
    res.end('hello');
  });
}

app = connect()
  .use(connect.router(route))
  ;

server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('listening on', server.address());
});
```

### On Github

https://github.com/coolaj86/connect_router taken from [Connect 1.x's router](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/1.x/lib/middleware/router.js) with documentation essentially being [the tests](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/1.x/test/router.test.js#L146)

The original documentation is... somewhere.